# Is MATLAB performace better than bash scripts for text manipulation?

Tags: performance, bash, matlab

I have a program (for simulation of some physical systems) that gives very big (more than 1GB) text files as output. I have to extract the desired results (numbers) from this text file. Currently I've written bash scripts for this purpose that, for example, search the text files for some expressions and write the number after that expression in a separate file; e.g.:

```
grep $EXP  | awk '{print $14}'  > tmp
```

Unfortunately, these bash scripts are very time-consuming for large input text files. So I am considering to use another language for searching the text files. As there are many scripts that I have to rewrite, does writing the scripts in MATLAB give me a considarable speed-up? 
As a side question, are there better options than MATLAB? (probably compiled languages like C?)

Comment: Maybe consider putting the files on a RAMdisk - even at 140MB/s off a fast disk you still have 7 seconds of I/O just to read it before you do any searching... How long is your searching taking?

Comment: @MarkSetchell For a 7GB file, more than 5 minutes.

Comment: You must be doing more than just `grep` in there! Or you have very slow disks. Try timing how long the actual read takes - preferably using an uncached file... `time cat 7GBfile > /dev/null`

Comment: Or, it may be the case that you find lots of results and your output file is also very large, is it? You can calculate how long your output is taking by timing your script but directing the results to `/dev/`null` instead of to disk.... `time grep xyz 7GBfile > /dev/null` If your output file is big, maybe you can arrange for your output file to be on a different disk from your input file.

Comment: You get an uncached file by rebooting, and not accessing the 7GB file before running the timing tests.

Comment: "...performance ... better than bash" doesn't seem to be the right question - you're most likely going to use some utility to extract from file, which is merely called from bash - therefore bash performance as such is irrelevant - unless you're intending to run bash through a loop, reading chunks from file, and using bash built-ins for searching on each read chunk of data.

Comment: Go is quite fast ( and easy to learn ) alternative. Python would be a good idea too. Scripting with metaprogramming language like bash/sh isn't the better solution just because the PID cost to init. You started a nice perspective when asking to yourself about use a programming language instead bash.